# Adding gadget in web page issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to embed [this](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pilyrics.com%2Fgadgets%2Fmoneyc.xml&lang=en) gadget in my web page. That's why I use the embedding code (given at last, "get code") given on it. However, can't understand how to show it in specific position say for example right-top or say for example 500, 500 px. Can anybody help me how can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a CSS question. What have you tried so far? Most likely you are going to need to style the `DIV` containing the gadget however you want to. That will be different for top-right and 500,500 fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it around a div and add styling. In the example top and right distance are set to zero pixels, if you want 20px from the top chagrin it to top:20x.
http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/uhPfr/

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0;">
    <script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.pilyrics.com/gadgets/moneyc.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=645&amp;title=LIVE+MARKET+RATES&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
</div>
```

​

Comment: Thanks a lot. But for me the above code outputs "#emb { 
 position: fixed; 
 right: 0; 
 top: 0;    
}" and below this the gadget is shown.

Comment: I don't know why is this happening any idea ?

Comment: @alessandro I'm editing the answer so it causes no confusion.